# Will Adblock Plus work with Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, firefox, adblock

I have ordered a System76 desktop preloaded with Ubuntu 13.10 and Firefox.  At apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/adblock-plus/, it only shows "Ubuntu 10.04" under "Available versions."

Comment: As a side note, I recommend using http://gaenserich.github.io/hostsblock/ (which includes a DEB file as well) instead of "Adblock Plus" addon for a better solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're referring to the ad block add-on for Firefox. Well, I'm quiet confused as to which you're referring to as **apps.ubuntu.com**; but I just had a quick look installing into my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (with the latest Firefox 27.0 version) which seems working fine.

If I'm not mistaken; Add-on support will effect only the web browser but not the operating system (correct me If I'm wrong). Also on the add-on download itself says that it support from Firefox 17.0 and later (as seen below); (that leads me to say, it should work for firefox version 17.0 and later)

[image]

## Screens from my system

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt depend on any desktop OS like linux, mac or windows. If you have Firefox installed, Adblock is just a add on, so it will work definitely.